# Connect cloud instance locally for laravel project running as service

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel-5, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect a Laravel to Google mysql instance locally.

.env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:GptV9AIxUX7TuPkKxbLs54DLjivt2wCmuG37qsnqxJU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=**********
DB_USERNAME=**********
DB_PASSWORD=**********
DB_SOCKET=/cloudsql/[INSTANCE NAME]
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

I am using this cloud_sql_proxy command:

```
~/Downloads/cloud_sql_proxy -instances=/cloudsql/[INSTANCE_ID]=tcp:3306
```

and it working properly,

```
2018/07/18 13:46:29 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for /cloudsql/[INSTANCE ID]
2018/07/18 13:46:29 Ready for new connections
```

I also enabled enabled **Google Cloud SQL** and **Cloud SQL Admin API** for my project.

The error I receive is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `campaigns`)
```

Below are my observation in struggle to find a solution.

1. In Stackdriver logging error that I see is

   severity:  "ERROR"
   textPayload:  "2018-07-18T05:57:08.204597Z 859643 [Note] Aborted connection 859643 to db: '[DB_NAME]' user: '[DB_USER]' host: 'cloudsqlproxy~173.194.90.33' (Got an error reading communication packets)"
2. When I check `~/Downloads/cloud_sql_proxy info`:

   2018/07/18 14:10:50 Using gcloud's active project: [PROJECT ID]
   2018/07/18 14:10:55 **must set -dir: using a unix socket for [INSTANCE NAME]**

I am actually not able to relate if this is related to error.

3. I have tried connecting cloud sql using service account, its connects properly but still not able to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to connect to Cloud SQL: via TCP or via a Unix Socket.

If you are using a Unix Socket, you need to specify `-dir /cloudsql` (or similar) as a directory to create your socket in. Full command looks something like this:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql -instances=myProject:uscentral1:myInstance
```

You would then use `DB_SOCKET=/cloudsql/myProject:uscentral1:myInstance` to connect. (You don't need a host or port - you're connecting via the unix socket)

If you are using TCP, you apply the port you want to listen to your instance name. So the command looks like this:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=myProject:us-central1:myInstance=tcp:3306
```

In this case, you use `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` and `DB_PORT=3306` (but not `DB_SOCKET`).

Comment: it worked with me.. I was using DB_SOCKET with DB_HOST and thats why it was throwing exception.. Thanks..